# Visual Studio Code is not reading my PNG files

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

for some reason the images (png) I uploaded to Visual Studio Code don't display.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code.

index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import router from './routes/index.js'
import path, {dirname, join} from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"


const app = express();

//VIEWS

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'views')) 

//STATICS

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')))


//ROUTES
app.use(router);


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000)
console.log('Server is listening on port', process.env.PORT || 2000);
```

homepage.js

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column cssbackground" style=" margin-top: 30px;">
   <img src="mapcr.png" alt="">
   <img src="src/mapcr.png" alt="">
   <img src="C:/Users/andre/OneDrive/Escritorio/MyTV/src/mapcr.png" alt="">
</div>
```

style.css

```
.cssbackground {
    background-image: url(“mapcr.png”);
}
```

As you can see in the homepage.js file, I have tried multiple paths to get the image "mapcr.png" to display but none of them work. I also tried setting it as a background-image in the CSS file but it didnt work either.

As a workaround I tried converting the PNG file into a URL but it doesnt work to set the image as background-image. :(

Here is also a picture of my directory. Please help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Express creates a server, and you told it to make the `public` directory available at the root of that server. If you put your image in that folder, you'll be able to display it by using `/mapcr.png`. Just like you're able to load `/css/style.css`

Comment: first teach me how you: `uploaded to Visual Studio Code`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with VSCode, VSCode doesn't change your code by itself in any way.

Your mapcr.png isn't in the same folder as your styles.css file.

You will first need to move the image to the /public folder. Then use:

```
.cssbackground {
    background-image: url("../mapcr.png");
}
```

`../` will make it go back a directory so it goes into the right directory.

You could also use `/` instead so it goes into the root directory.

```
.cssbackground {
    background-image: url("/mapcr.png");
}
```

Comment: The Express server won't allow you to go above the `public` directory by using `..`. Imagine what a security issue that would create! Users would be able to browse the entire server file system. Just put the image in the `public` directory, declared as a static entry point in the OP's code

Comment: I didn't see that, I will change the answer.